# ASP.NET chat client

Tags: asp.net, extjs, chat, .net-1.1

What's my best bet for implementing a simple chat client (2-person) in an ASP.NET 1.1 application? I'm using ExtJS for the front-end so if it integrates well with that it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using web services and AJAX but you'll have to hand code it all if you're using 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

if you just look for free see this
http://steveorr.net/Articles/WebChat.aspx